# json post to devise causes 422 / Unprocessable entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

i'm using angular and posting to a RoR back-end, with devise for auth. When I submit a new user for creation, I'm getting the following:

```
Started PUT "/api/user" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-19 11:38:13 -0600
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"alex@someemail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "first_name"=>"alex", "last_name"=>"p"}, "registration"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"alex@someemail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "first_name"=>"alex", "last_name"=>"p"}}}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'alex@someemail.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 128ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 7.4ms)
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :last_check

end
```

I can't figure out what's going on. I assume it's something with the parameters I'm sending (or not sending?) but everything seems to be there.

Comment: Actually having the same problem. On the create method of devise the `if resource.save?` fails and causes that problem!

Comment: I am to having the same issue. 
But i dont have any user in my db with same email.
Using postman to issue requests.
Any sugesstions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My first thought base on the log is that there is already a user existing with the same email. Otherwise you can use a httpclient (curl or Postman in chrome or Restclient in chrome) to see what the response is.

I'm not too familiar with Angular but if you do have access to the http response just output it in the console. It should tell you the validation errors.

Comment: sigh. `"{"errors":{"password":["is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]}}"`. didn't even occur to me that it was sending a verbose response to the client.

Comment: hehe! FYI you can change this password config in config/initializers/devise.rb (config.password_length)

Comment: @kolosy I had the same problem, and the cause of the problem turns out to be the same as yours. That was weird.

Comment: This helped me on something similar. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

If use still facing same issue by using different email then I think you are not passing expected JSON data to controller. If you are not passing email and password with users resource then that was possible reason too.

Correct JSON format to pass data for user creation :

```
{
    "user":{
        "email" : "Helloworld@gmail.com",
        "password": "121212",
        "password_confirmation": "121212"
    }
}
```